# UV map in UV Editing does not match UV map seen in Edit mode

Tags: uv

[image]

Help, I dunno how I messed this up. All I remember is switching UVs for the face and this happened...

The UV map on the left is NOT the UV for the body but the face.

Before, when I selected the body's mesh, it shows the body's UV and when I select the face mesh, it will switch to the Face's UV.

Now it's stuck on just one UV in UV editing

I'm new to Blender so I don't know what's going on...

Comment: If you switch from a mesh to another it won't switch from an image to another in the UV editor, at least not that I know even if it could seem logical, it will keep the selected image, and if you want to display the image linked to the selected mesh you need to find the image in the UV editor dropdown menu.

Comment: The UV editor won't automatically do that?

Comment: no, I was also surprised because that's what I would have expected

Comment: Unfortunate. Thanks for clearing that up. :)